# Retrieving a maximum value from a SUMMARIZECOLUMNS table

Tags: dax

I have a query and the following results, executed from DAX Studio:

[image]

What I would like to do now is to expand the query so that I can retrieve maximum Total Sales from the table that SUMMARIZECOLUMNS produces. For example, based on the rows displayed in the results, I'd like a way to return 10234.35. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the whole `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS` part in a `MAXX`.

```
MAXX(
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS([...]),
    [Total Sales]
)
```

The [`MAXX(<table>,<expression>)` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/maxx-function-dax) iterates through each row of the `<table>` from its first argument taking the maximum value of the `<expression>` in the second argument.

---

As @greggyb points out, a more efficient implementation would be

```
CALCULATE (
    MAXX ( VALUES ( Customers[Customer Key] ), [Sales Amount] ),
    FILTER ( Products, Products[Product Name] = "Fabrikam Laptop12v M2080 Silver" ),
    FILTER ( 'Calendar', 'Calendar'[Calendary Year] = 2008 )
)
```

since this doesn't require creating the whole summary table in memory.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Nota bene: you can refactor to a `CALCULATE ( MAXX ( VALUES ( 'Customers'[CustomerKey] ), [Sales Amount] ), FILTER ( ... ), FILTER ( ... ) )` and likely see a good bump in performance. The first argument to `MAXX` is transiently materialized in memory. The larger that table, the more memory bandwidth required. In general, iterating the minimum set of columns possible is best.